# Errors in eclipse while running Wildfly

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly

When I try to start Wildfly using eclipse I get this warnings and errors:

```
WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYTX0013: Node identifier property is set to the default value. Please make sure it is unique.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore D:\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0091: -ds.xml file deployments are deprecated. Support may be removed in a future version.
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Scopes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./Scopes.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.htfhere.servlets.SimpleServlet from [Module "deployment.Scopes.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

And i think this is the reason why I cant run any eclipse application with JPA. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The error means your deployment is missing one of its dependencies, `pl.htfhere.servlets.SimpleServlet` ; there may be an additional stacktrace above explaining why this dependency isn't available (i.e. if the class is itself available but missing a dependency). Otherwise the class just isn't accessible from your deployment's classpath. The three WARN lines likely have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: It looks like `pl.htfhere.servlets.SimpleServlet` isn't in your deployment. You may have an entry for it in your `web.xml`.